# loader issue with react-day-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

While using react-day-picker, i get the following error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.  
| /* DayPicker styles */ |  
 | .DayPicker { | display: -webkit-box; |  

display: -ms-flexbox; @  
 ./src/components/portfolio/RecordInvestorDetail.react.js 47:0-41  

Module parse failed: /home/yash/Documents/CRONJ/waccal/node_modules/react-day-picker/lib/style.css Line 3: Unexpected token .
```

_

[image]

Comment: Could you share your webpack config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error by adding

```
loaders : [
'style',
]
```

I already had

```
loaders : [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version',
          'sass-loader?includePaths[]=' + paths.src('styles')
        ]
```

Now the loaders are

```
loaders : [
          'style',
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version',
          'sass-loader?includePaths[]=' + paths.src('styles')
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You must install and enable [`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) and [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) for Webpack:

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

Then add those loaders in `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this configuration before:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
}
```

And got the issue fixed by removing the line:
exclude: /node_modules/

I wasnt allowing webpack to compile the files from react-day-picker by having this.

the correct:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
}
```